# Data Studio - TODATE(input, "%Y%m") Is One Month Behind

Tags: google-analytics, looker-studio

I would like to plot a time series by month, but my input data is formatted as "%Y-%m-%d".  So, I create another time dimension with the following formula:

```
TODATE(date, "%Y%M")
```

My issue is that the new dimension is one month behind what it should be.  For example, an input date of '2017-08-15' results in '2017-07' (or that information in whatever data studio's internal date structure is).  The result is that changes in the time series metric appear to have occurred a month earlier than they actually did. Here are screenshots of a toy example with google sheets data and the resulting plot.  Note that the time series plot is set to cumulative:

Data with an increase in count for August:
[image: Data with an increase in count for August]

Time series plot showing an increase in count in July:
[image: Time series plot showing an increase in count in July]

The increase in count in August of 2017 appears to have occurred in July. Although these data are from sheets, the data from my actual issue are from a Postgres DB table, so I don't imagine it's an issue with the data source. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Similar problem:

1. `todate(date, 'DEFAULT_DASH', "%m %Y")` resulted in a "month year" configuration that was one month behind.
2. Furthermore, the use of the proposed date format in the data type field to YYYYMM did not work as well.

Solution (for me): I solved by first using the todate function with inclusion of the day (i.e. `todate(date, 'DEFAULT_DASH', "%d %m %Y"`) and then setting the date format to Year Month (`YYYYMM`).

Answer (score 1):

Nothing from the listed solutions worked for me. I noticed, however, that

```
TODATE(start_date,'%Y%m%d','%m')
```

gives the **right** month.

I therefore went for a pinch of overkill:

1. `CONCAT(TODATE(start_date,'%Y%m%d','%Y'),TODATE(start_date,'%Y%m%d','%m'))`
2. Convert to YYYYMM, or '%Y%m' in the source field list.

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple fix, not sure how I overlooked it. Instead of using the function `TODATE()`, simply change the date format in the data type field to YYYYMM. I must have assumed that this field corresponded to the input format, not output:

[image: Change date format in edit data source]

Answer (score 0):

Do note `%M` stands for Minute, not Month. `%m` would be considered a 'month' value.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was:

```
todate(concat(start_date, '01'), '%Y%m%d', '%Y%m%d')
```

then choose the date > `YYYYmm` format.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem.
I fixed it using the [`PARSE_DATE`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9739156) function.

I have two columns, one with the year and other with the month.
First, I [`CONCAT`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7583443) both of them like this:

[image]

This gives me something like "2022/01"

After this, I only need to use the [`PARSE_DATE`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9739156) function like this.

[image]

Which gives me the end result. Being the value: a date with 2022/01. Not like 2021/12.

Comment: Could you also copy-paste the respective formulas (images are optional); also, add a quick note to mention that `fecha-cierre` is the name of the respective field create in image 1; in addition, note that the fields in the question did not include a separate Year or month field thus sub formulas may be required in this specific case, for example, `CONCAT(YEAR(Date),......)` where [`YEAR`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7583314) is a function